# Accessing object T in vector<unique_ptr<T>> without taking ownership

Tags: c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I have the following member variable in a class:
    `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects_`;

I explicitly want the vector to maintain ownership at all times. I've seen suggestions that in order for a member function to access a pointer in the vector and make changes to the object `T` wrapped in the `std::unique_ptr`, we must move the pointer to calling code, i.e:

```
    void foo(int i) {
        auto object = std::move( vector.at( i ) );  // move object to caller (caller owns)
        object->dosomething(); 
        vector.at(i) = std::move(object); // move back into vector (vector owns)
    }
```

Another method was to work with raw pointers:

```
    void foo(int i) {
        Object* object = vector.at( i ).get();
        object->doSomething();
    }
```

However, I've been working with this:

```
    void foo(int i) {
        auto& object = vector.at( i );
        object->doSomething();
    }
```

Which is the correct and most robust method for my case? Does this function ever take ownership of the data in the `std::unique_ptr`? Is there a way to access `Object` without playing with the `std::unique_ptr`?

(excuse me if my methods are incorrect, I hope I got the point across)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach will not retain ownership of the object if `object->dosomething()` throws an exception (i.e. it is not exception safe) since the second `std::move()` statement will not be executed.

Assuming C++11, both of the other approaches are effectively equivalent, subject to the assumption that the owned pointer is not null.   Under the same assumption, the code can be simplified to

```
void foo(int i)
{
    vector.at(i)->doSomething();
}
```

which will work with all C++ standards (not just C++11 or later).

It is possible to access the object without monkeying with the `unique_ptr` - simply store the pointer elsewhere and use that.   However, that does compromise the purpose of using `std::unique_ptr` in the first place.   And is error-prone - for example, the `std::unique_ptr` can destroy the object, and leave those other pointers dangling.

If you are really that worried about the potential of your vector losing ownership, consider using a `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: Doh! Of course that simplification works! I've clearly been staring at this for far too long.